# Is it possible to use jqueryaop within an angularjs app?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, aop

I would like to add AOP on my AngularJS application. Typically I would like to check every function being executed in the services, controlles and directives before and after. Hence I would like to choose jQuery AOP for this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple AOP library for AngularJS https://github.com/mgechev/angular-aop

I guess it can be extended and improved, it's still in initial phase of development.